# Set Zend Framework 2 form element to disabled

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having problems setting a form element to disabled. I thought it would be

```
$dropDownForCheckBox = new Element\Select("asdf");
$dropDownForCheckBox->setOptions(['disabled', true]);
```

However, that does not produce the disabled attribute that I would expect.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use disabled attribute instead of setting element options:

```
$dropDownForCheckBox->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```